# How to keep the List items in recyclerview after loading the list from server

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

In my app there is a RecyclerView and I load the the list from server, but after that I want to keep that loaded RecyclerView as it is like we see in WhatsApp. I don't want to load the data again after moving to other fragment in viewpager. we can store in local db and retrieve the list and load into recyclerview but this method doesn't work for me because this one also loads the data whenever I change the viewpager.

How can I solve this? 
I have searched over google for this but didn't find it anywhere.

Comment: What is the issue with storing it in local database ?

Comment: put your code where you are setting view pager

Comment: If we store the list in local database, when I start the activity A or fragment A the ListData will be loaded into recyclverview, but when I move to fragment B and come back to the Fragment A the recyclerview will load the date again from db and the user have to wait till the list loads again.

Comment: @Krishna Have you considered the possibility of having a singleton that holds your data. Something like ChatStore. Once you query the web you update that list if needed, check for duplicates etc. Your adapter is the one that is "looking" at that list and you notify items inserted or data set changed only when it "really" changes. Its easier to maintain data throughout your app.